# How can I access my Postgres database on my desktop from my laptop when I travel?

Tags: postgresql

I have a desktop and a laptop.  Can I store Postgres online somewhere so that both of my desktop and laptop can access the database? Sorry for this simple question. I am a new student of database.

Comment: Yes! Most database servers run in a datacenter and are accessed over the internet.

Comment: This is likely too basic for StackOverflow. You need a server running Postgres accessible to the Internet. You can run this server yourself, or use a managed service such as [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases-postgresql), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/), or [Elephant SQL](https://www.elephantsql.com/). Many have free plans for small databases.

Answer (score 2):

To access your database anywhere you can either:

- find a cloud service offering a postgres database, configure it with your data and then connect both your desktop and laptop to it
- setup a VPS with a postgres service exposing the required ports and connect your devices to it
- configure your desktop to run postgres locally, expose the ports, configure your router to do the port forwarding and configure a reverse DNS service (such as duckDuckGo) to bind your home IP to a static subdomain url.

Comment: Hello Niccolo, I am very interested in learning about the 3rd option that you wrote (configure my desktop so that the laptop can connect to the desktop). Could you point me to some places where I can learn more about this topic? This is completely new to me. Thank you for writing to help!

Comment: @TimB: 3rd option is pretty dangerous, you have to know how to secure your network and computer. If you don’t have the experience needed, your computers will be hacked and abused. Advice: don’t start with this option, just use AWS, Azure or GPC to get started in the cloud and let them keep things secure for you

Comment: I agree with @FrankHeikens, I mentioned the third option for completeness, however you can think of applying that only if you have a strong knowledge of what you are doing since exposing your local network might be quite dangerous. Since you are new to this topic, I suggest you to follow the first option.

Comment: Fourth option. Install Postgres on your desktop. Install an SSH server and client (OpenSSH being one) on desk-top/lap-top as appropriate Then create an SSH Tunnel from lap-top to desk-top. See Postgres documentation for [Secure TCP/IP Connections with SSH Tunnels](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssh-tunnels.html).

Comment: I am grateful for your writing to explain the various solutions and their associated risks. I have a lot to learn.  Also thank you the writer Belayer for pointing out the SSH Tunnels.  I will read up on it as well.  As being a new student, I want to keep the costs low as the database is only for personal use. Thanks again!!!